# D3 - How to merge 2 arrays based on their row index

Tags: javascript, d3.js, collections

I am working on visualization using D3 and need to merge 2 arrays based on row index:

```
var links = 
[
{"source":"a0","target":"a0","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"a","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"}  
];

var files =
[
{"File_Desc":"","DataName":""},
{"File_Desc":"Date","DataName":"Dates.01012016"},
{"File_Desc":"Address","DataName":"Address.01012016"}    
    ];
```

To get:

```
var result =
[
{"source":"a0","target":"a0","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"a","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"","DataName":""},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"Date","DataName":"Dates.01012016"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"Address","DataName":"Address.01012016"}
]
```

Comment: If these are the data you will be using, then just merge them manually and delete the question. If the data comes from two files or data sources and that data is quite large, hard to tackle manually than you will need a script to do it. You could utilize classical "for" loop where each link coresponds to each result i.e relation one on one. Are there some specific requirements that are not explained?

Comment: @Vlad - Dataset comes in 1 file and it is pretty big. I am working on force directed graph where link width is based on number of connections. And when I tried to pass entire array (without dividing it into two) I could not calculate number of connections between the nodes.

Comment: Any sort of graph is actually a data structure so you should view it as a data structure. A graph is a structure contained of nodes and links between the nodes. You could use adjacency matrix to explain which node is connected with which node. And of course add more details for the links and maybe link weight which is calculated based on the links to one node maybe?

Comment: @Vlad - Thank you for your feedback. I am new to D3 and JavaScript. But I will definitely look into adjacency matrix.

Comment: Luckily I was reworking this force directed graph http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3104394 and you can check the optimized code here: https://github.com/bluePlayer/practices/tree/master/D3js%20Exercises/ForceLayoutClickToGroupNodesMultiRelations Sadly it is made in D3 version 2.

Comment: Graphs do no exist only in JavaScript, all languages can create graphs. Adjacency matrix is from Graph Theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Comment: This graph you were reworking was the one I wanted to implement as well. But this code is so extensive that I could not understand it.

Comment: Yes it contains lot of garbage code. But the reworked one is better looking. If you could read it carefully, step by step. :)

Comment: @Vlad - Hi, Vlad! Was wondering if you ever came across this challenge: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286219/d3-js-how-to-display-link-related-data-in-a-pop-up-window-such-as-source-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use late model JavaScript (aka ES2015),
the shortest path is something like:

```
var result = links.map((d,i) => Object.assign({}, d, files[i]));
```

This is short. It also doesn't modify either `links` or `files` (should you wish to use them stand-alone separately from `result`).

**P.S.**

The comments suggest you're concerned about the runtime of the alternative solutions. In general, they're all okay, esp. as the kind of one-time data setup common in d3 apps. But, if you have large datasets or run record merges often, then you might want to optimize.

If you're willing to update one of your existing record sets rather than create a fresh new one:

```
links.forEach((d,i) => Object.assign(d, files[i]));
```

After this, `links` has the updated records. This runs 7-10x faster than the other solutions, presumably because it's not creating a ton of new objects. If you're done with the original, un-merged `links` or `files` objects, there's no particular reason to avoid this kind of "destructive" or "in place" update. There's often little need to optimize one-time setup operations. But if you wanted or needed to do so, this is a strong way.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. Is there performance difference with what @dave suggested below?

Comment: @Alexey Both complete in single-digit milliseconds, but dave's is faster. If you're dealing with large datasets or doing this operation hundreds or thousands of times, the delta could be significant. In most cases, it's not. If you're only doing this once as part of data initialization, it's immaterial.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var links = [
  {"source":"a0","target":"a0","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"a","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"},
  {"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"},
  {"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP"}  
];

var files = [
  {"File_Desc":"","DataName":""},
  {"File_Desc":"Date","DataName":"Dates.01012016"},
  {"File_Desc":"Address","DataName":"Address.01012016"}    
];

var result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  result[i] = Object.assign(links[i], files[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: When I run console.log(result); File_Desc and DataName are null everywhere. Any idea why?

Comment: @Alexey your `result[0]["DataName"] === ""` so it will print nothing but `console.log(result[1]["DataName"]);` prints `Dates.01012016`. If your `console.log(result[1]["DataName"]);` prints something else, you have a problem in your code somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably iterate over one array with an [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then in my callback function return a combined object using a function such as the one defined in [this answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var result = links.map(combineLinkToFile);

function combineLinkToFile (link, index) {

    var file = files[index];

    return collect(link, file)
}

function collect() {
  var ret = {};
  var len = arguments.length;
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    for (p in arguments[i]) {
      if (arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        ret[p] = arguments[i][p];
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. Is there performance difference with what @Jonathan Eunice suggested above?

Comment: I don't know about performance difference. Probably best to test that yourself if it's important to you. But Object.assign has more limited browser support, so you may not want to use it for the front-end. I like Jonathan's answer better if you're able to use Object.assign though.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery map() and extend() methods:

```
function mergeObjectsInArrays(arr1, arr2){
    return $.map(arr1, function(el, i){
        return $.extend(el, arr2[i]);
    });
};

// then pass your arrays:
var result = mergeObjectsInArrays(links, files);
```

Comment: OP may not be using jQuery. I see no reason to introduce it if he isn't. This can be done pretty easily in vanilla JS.

Comment: and thanks for provide insight, @dave. I was curious why my answer would have been downvoted.