# d3.js - How to display link related data in a pop-up window (such as source and target)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am looking for a way to display link related data in a pop-up window when link is clicked.

One link may include information about multiple connections between nodes.

As an example:
A1 and A2 are my nodes.
A1 sends to A2 two files, A2 sends to A1 1 file.
When clicking the link connecting nodes A1 and A2 I would like to see what files are being sent, and from where to where (direction). I have a working function where on node click I get a pop-up window which displays node-related data. I need to do similar with the links.
 Fiddle is here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey_D3/xhx3L8jn/29/

```
var dashboard2 = d3.select("body").append("section2")
    .attr("class", dashboard2)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);  

function linkClick (d) {

if($.inArray(d.source, d.target, items) !== -1){return}                                                           
    if (dashboard2.data && d.source === dashboard2.data.source) {
        dashboard2.style("visibility", "visible")
        return;     }

        dashboard2.data = d;
    d3.selectAll(".text-tip2").remove();


dashboard2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text-tip2").text(d.source)
    .style("display", "block")
    .style("color", "black")
    .style("padding", "15px")
    .style("font-family", "roboto")
    .style("font-size", "20px");

dashboard2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text-tip2").text(d.target)
    .style("display", "block")
    .style("color", "black")
    .style("padding", "15px")
    .style("font-family", "roboto")
    .style("font-size", "20px");

dashboard2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text-tip2").text("File Description: " + d.File_Desc);   

dashboard2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text-tip2").text("File Name: " + d.DataName);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.text(d.source)
```

and

```
.text(d.target)
```

It has to be:

```
.text(d.source.name)
```

And

```
.text(d.target.name)
```

Regarding "File description" and "File name", there is nothing I can do because you don't have neither `File_Desc` nor `DataName` properties in your `links` array.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zygj0nkj/

Comment: Thank you. Does it help that I have another array "result" that contains both arrays links and files?